# Calling a function with close to real time interval

Tags: c++, windows, cross-platform

I am working on a simulation project and I have come across a problem.

I have function called `step()` which is called by a loop in `main()`.

This function needs to be called in exact real-time interval. I have implemented a solution `with std::this_thread::sleep_for` but, as it says, it sleeps for `at least` the given time. The problem gets bigger as the steps gets smaller. The difference between real-time (ahead) and simulation time becomes 1 sec at 10th sec of actual time elapsed, using 20ms step.

I have came across [multimedia timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712704%28VS.85%29.aspx), I have two questions before implementing it.

Is there a cross platform approach to this instead of [multimedia timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712704%28VS.85%29.aspx)? (except the obvious cpu killer `while();` loop)

Are multimedia timers enough for at least 1ms thread suspension & resume accuracy?

Comment: Windows is not a real time OS. So, what exactly do you mean by "real time"?

Comment: I know, but I suppose there should be a way to get at least 1ms accuracy since there are simulation programs for Windows platform.

Comment: I guess you need to avoid using the term "real time". Also, what is "lagless suspension accuracy"?

Comment: The granularity of your simulation is independent of the underlying OS it's running on, why do you think you need exact timings?

Comment: @David Heffernan I have edited that. I meant the delay added to X that is happening before resuming of a thread that is suspended with sleep(X).

Comment: @doomster, I am requested to get as close as I can get to exact timings. I am wondering if there is a convenient way to do that.

Comment: Tolga, we are misunderstanding each other, so much is clear. ;) What I'm trying to say is that a simulation can run faster or slower than the process it is simulating. If you want, you can write your simulation to make steps of one millisecond, even if that takes longer or less long on a different computer. The simulation outcome will be the same.

Comment: @doomster, I guess I should try to explain further. here is what I am trying to implement: I have to choose the timeStep as small as possible for each calculation (lets say position = velocity * timeStep) for the sake of precision of checks. (e.g. the person needs to react to the situation as fast as possible while moving, not 2 meters late).
Yet I have to do just enough calculations in unit time to synchronize the simulation world time with real world time. Maybe my approach is wrong?

Comment: Ah, got it. You need interaction, so the simulation can't run in arbitrary time intervals. In that case, I'd just determine the stepwidth from the elapsed time. Using timeGetTime(), you can determine this time in milliseconds easily. I don't know of any portable alternative to that, not even an equivalent for POSIX systems. If you happen to find one, please drop a note here!

Comment: @doomster Getting the time is easy. The problem is waiting exactly for the specified time. I will look further I guess.

Comment: It sounds to me as if your problem is not that the OS can't sleep for exactly the right amount of time, but that you're sleeping for a fixed amount of time each loop rather than allowing for the extra elapsed time due to sleep() overruns as well as due to the processing time for the step() function.  Does it work better if you calculate the time that a given step should end (based on the time that the first step started) and then sleep until that time?